# Why is this reference not working/ valid?

Tags: c, reference

I'm learning referencing in C and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;

    int &ref = x;

    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%p\n", &x);     
    printf("%p\n", &ref);

    return 0;
}
```

When i compile, it shows these errors:

> reference.c:7:6: error: expected identifier or '('
>
> int &ref = x;
>
> reference.c:11:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ref'
>
> printf("%p\n", &ref);
>
> 2 errors generated.

What should i do to fix this and thanks in advance.

Comment: `int &ref` looks like C++, not C.

Comment: C doesn't have references. C++ does. It looks like you are trying to compile C++ code with a C compiler.

Comment: Change `int &ref = x;` to `int *ref = &x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "reference" in C is called a pointer. Through the pointer you reference something. In your code you need to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;

    int *ref = &x;           // now ref points to x

    printf("%d\n", x);       // print the value of x
    printf("%p\n", &x);      // print the address of x
    printf("%p\n", &ref);    // print the address of the pointer variable
    printf("%d\n", *ref);    // print the value of the int that ref is pointing to
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I was reading the concept of a pointer and the code is in C++ so I translated them into c since they are similar (I'm learning c as my first language). Apparently, c++ has references but c does not.

Comment: Calling  a pointer in C a "reference" is confusing, since in  C++ a reference is different than a pointer. But you would be right in saying that a pointer can often do the same job as a reference

Answer (score 4):

c does not have a reference type, you can only use point instead of ref.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 5;

    int *ref = &x;

    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%p\n", &x);
    printf("%p\n", &ref);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Small point, it is better to put the star next to the identifier name, because in the case of say `int* ref, point;` the variable `point` is *not* a pointer. The `*` modifies the following variable, not the preceding type.

Comment: @WeatherVane or you could avoid declaring multiple pointers in one declaration and not have that problem. There's nothing wrong with `int* ref`

Comment: @WeatherVane i fix it, ths

Comment: @M.M true and it's been edited.

Comment: @M.M Although I also like to put * in front, but redis, nginx are placed behind